# How to grab HTML elements in aspx.cs file (checkbox) C#

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox, server-side

Let's say I have I have something along the lines of (in my aspx file):

```
<input name="chk" id="cbox1" type="checkbox">
<input name="chk" id="cbox2" type="checkbox">
<input name="chk" id="cbox3" type="checkbox">
<input name="chk" id="cbox4" type="checkbox">
```

---

How would I be able to get the value of each element inside the .aspx.cs file?
Can I call something like GetElementsByName in C#?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't, unless you will mark this controls as `runat="server"`.

This is because in ASP.NET all static html became a `Literal` control with `.Text` property equal to your html. In this case it will be:

```
<asp:Literal>
    <input name="chk" id="cbox1" type="checkbox">
    <input name="chk" id="cbox2" type="checkbox">
    <input name="chk" id="cbox3" type="checkbox">
    <input name="chk" id="cbox4" type="checkbox">
</asp:Literal>
```

If you will mark any of elements as `runat="server"`, you can access them from `.Controls` collection of the current page.

Or (as in other answer) you can use the server control (`CheckBox` or `CheckBoxList`) for such inputs

Comment: Not correct - you don't have to set the runat="server" atrribute, you can access the values using something like : string values = Request["chk"].ToString(); ?

Comment: yes, agree'd you can't "SET" values this way, but he asked how to "GET" the values ?

Comment: @Dave Long You can't get values from them on first page load, are they checked or not - only after submit. I don't think @googlesearchsentmehere meant get values after submit.

Comment: ok, fair enough - in that case, I agree that you would have to make them server controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the aspx file instead:  `<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbox1">`

Then in your code behind, call `cbox1.Checked` to see if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You need add the attribute runat with the value server, lie so.

```
<input name="chk" id="cbox4" type="checkbox" runat="server">
```

Then you can do this.

```
var val = cbox4.value;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `this.Request.Form`. Use it like this:

```
this.Request.Form["ElementID"].
```

Answer (score -2):

Using the runat="server"

> `<input name="cbox1" id="cbox1" runat="server" type="checkbox">`

You can use it directly like:

> cbox1.Checked